# How to underline TextView in xml (Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: xamarin.android, textview, underline

I have to underline the TextViews of the following table:

[image]

The only thing I found in internet is:

http://www.apnatutorials.com/android/how-to-underline-text-in-android.php?categoryId=2 (Approach 4)

But the value of the text in that case is hardcoded. In my case there are 9 rows which can change its number. So hardcoding is not solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

> How to underline TextView in xml (Xamarin.Android)?

You could create a custom `TextView` and use it in your `.axml` file.

Create an underline `TextView` class:

```
public class UnderlineTextView : TextView
{
    public UnderlineTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base(context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public UnderlineTextView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        //this.PaintFlags = this.PaintFlags | Android.Graphics.PaintFlags.UnderlineText;
        //this.Text = "This text will be underlined";

        String underlineData = this.Text;
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(underlineData);
        content.SetSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, underlineData.Length, 0);
        // 0 specify start index and underlineData.length() specify end index of styling
        this.TextFormatted = content;
    }
}
```

Then, use it in `axml`:

```
<yournamespace.UnderlineTextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I am underline TextView"/>
```